# Adding a transition only for an image

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Suppose I have a slide defined as follows:

```
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]{Some Slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\item Another item
\end{itemize}

\pause

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]

\transdissolve
\transduration{2}

\node[yshift=78] (img2)   {\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{someimage.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{frame}
```

Now I want *only* the image to be show with a transition. In the above code, with the transition command added inside the `tikzpicture` environment, the complete slide as well as image are drawn with a transition. How do I restrict the transition to the image only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]{Some Slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\item Another item
\end{itemize}

\transdissolve<2>
\transduration{2}
\only<2>{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \node[yshift=78] (img2) {\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{dummy.png}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For more information visit section 14.3 of the excellent `beamer` [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

(Be aware of the fact that transitions are in most cases really distracting. Always keep this in mind and rethink before using them.)